# Creating a 2d array for textboxes

Tags: c#, arrays, textbox, 2d

So I'm trying to create an 8X8 grid of textboxes. I want to have the ability to also access the textboxes when I need to search through them. I have looked into considering an embedded List (i.e. `List<List<TextBoxes>>`) Where the inner list has 8 slots and the outer lists also has 8. I was wondering if there was an easier way.

Also how would I add my textboxes from my form into this 2d array?

Thanks for the help.

-Lewis

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a `TextBox[,]` for this purpose:

```
private TextBox[,] textboxes;

public YourClass() {
    // Add this after the text boxes have actually been set up...

    textboxes = new TextBox[,] {
        {textbox00, textbox01, textbox02, ...},
        {textbox10, textbox11, textbox12, ...},
        ,,,
    };
}
```

Then you can access `textbox00` as `textboxes[0,0]`, `textbox56` as `textboxes[5,6]`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
private class Position
{
    internal int Row;
    internal int Col;
}

var txtBoxesDict=new Dictionary<Position, TextBox>();

txtBoxesDict.Add(new Position{Row=0,Col=0},txtBox0);
```

To access thrid textbox in fourth row, you can use:

```
MessageBox.Show(txtBoxesDict[new Position{Row=3, Col=2}].Text);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a standard 2D array TextBoxes[8,8]